# How to extract href content using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, href

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/atl/atlanta-hawks')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
player_list = soup.find_all(class_="Image__Wrapper")
#player_list = soup.find_all("tr")
print(player_list[1])
```

The output I get is

```
<div class="Image__Wrapper aspect-ratio--child"><img alt="https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/nba/players/full/3062667.png" class="" data-mptype="image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" title="DeAndre' Bembry"/></div>
```

I am interested in only getting DeAndre' Bembry, how do I extract that. I am also a bit confused how to get the list of all the players names.

Comment: Where is the output?

Comment: Andrej updated the output, you see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://espn.go.com/nba/team/roster/_/name/atl/atlanta-hawks')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
player_list = soup.find_all(class_="Image__Wrapper")
#player_list = soup.find_all("tr")
print(player_list[1].img["title"])
```

Output

```
 DeAndre' Bembry
```

And to print all players

```
print([i.img["title"] for i in player_list if 0 < i.img["title"].count(" ") <= 3])
```

Output

```
["DeAndre' Bembry", 'Charlie Brown Jr.', 'Clint Capela', 'Vince Carter', 'John Collins', 'Dewayne Dedmon', 'Bruno Fernando', 'Brandon Goodwin', 'Treveon Graham', 'Kevin Huerter', "De'Andre Hunter", 'Damian Jones', 'Skal Labissiere', 'Cam Reddish', 'Jeff Teague', 'Trae Young']
```

Comment: thank you, and how do I go by getting all the list of the names? without manually printing each index?

Comment: print([i.img["title"] for i in player_list])

Comment: one last question why did u put if 0 < <=3, I even put <=5 and it really did not change anything

Comment: This was to remove some sentences that not players names.

Answer (score 0):

```
player_list[1].find_next('img').get('title')  # "DeAndre' Bembry"
```

Comment: thank you, and how do I go by getting all the list of the names?